# Vue, почему свойство вызывается со старым значением?

Tags: vue.js

Доброе утро, такая проблема с вью: есть массив список фильмов, есть указатель current. К примеру указатель равен 0 и я вызываю метод currentPart() и записываю часть массива от 0 до 59 индекса и потом изменяю указатель, но когда вызываю еще раз указатель снова равен 0, а должен 60.
Сам код:

```
<template>
  <main class='list-movies'>
    <header class='header'>
      {{ textHead }}
    </header>
    <ul class='movies'>
      <Movie
        v-for='movie in movies'
        :key='movie.name'
        :movie='movie'
      />
    </ul>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import Movie from './Movie'
import moviesList from '../../sources/movies.js'
export default {
  name: 'ListMovie',
  components: {
    Movie
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      textHead: 'Каталог фильмов по всем жанрам',
      current: 0,
      total: 60,
      movies: []
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    localStorage.clear()
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies')) === null ? 
      this.currentPart(this.current, this.current+60) :
      this.movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'))
    localStorage.getItem('current') === null ?
      this.current += 60 :
      this.current = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('current'))
    localStorage.getItem('total') === null ?
      this.total = 60 :
      this.total = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('total'))
    window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    localStorage.setItem('current', this.current)
    localStorage.setItem('total', this.total)
    localStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(this.movies))
  },
    destroyed: function () {
    alert('fdgsdfdfg')
        window.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll)
    },
  methods: {
    currentPart: function (current, point) {
      console.log(current, this.current) 
      for (current; current < point; ++current) {
        this.movies.push(moviesList[current])
      }

    },
    nextPart: function () {
      if (this.total < 180) this.currentPart(this.current, this.current+60)
      else if (this.total > 180) {
        this.movies = []
        this.currentPart(this.current-120, this.current+60)
      }
    },
    previosPart: function () {
      if (this.total > 180) {
        this.movies = []
        this.currentPart(this.current-180, this.current)
      }
    },
    handleScroll: function (e) {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        this.nextPart()
        this.current < moviesList.length-60 ? this.current += 60 : null
        this.total <= 180 ? this.total += 60 : null
      } else if (this.current !== 120 && document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0) {
        this.previosPart()
        this.current !== 0 ? this.current -= 60 : null
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .header {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .list-movies {
    padding: 0.8em;
  }
  .movies {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
</style>
```

И всё это сломалось когда интегрировал localStorage

Comment: Проблема только когда изменяете на 60? остальные значения применяются нормально?

Comment: Да, дальше всё нормально

Comment: А this случайно не изменился? Можно посмотреть в отладчике что такое this, временно убрать localStorage чтобы снова все заработало, и снова посмотреть в отладчике чем был this раньше. Всякое бывает.